# SQL 'Order By' Clause Appears to Work, but Returns Unsorted Data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

I have this table valued function in SQL Server 2014. The important part is the 'ORDER BY' at the end, which seems to be not doing anything. The end result is the same if I take it out or remove the DESC. Why would this be? I'd generally expect it to order by most recent -> least recent when used this way.

```
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @result (Id, Name, Description, TypeID, Date)
        select b.ID, b.Name, b.Description, b.TypeID, max(Date) from BTable b
        inner join ATTable at on b.atID = at.ID
        inner join STATTable stat on at.ID= stat.atID
        inner join CCTable cc on stat.stID= cc.stID
        inner join STTAble st on cc.stID= st.ID
        inner join TSTable ts on ts.cID = @cID and ts.bID = b.ID
            where b.Active = 1 and at.Active = 1 and stat.Active = 1 and cc.Active = 1 and st.Type = 1 AND 
                cc.cID = @cId and (b.cID IS NULL OR b.cID = @cId) and b.aID = (Select c.aID from CTable c where c.ID = @cId)
        GROUP BY b.ID, b.Name, b.Description, b.atID
        ORDER BY Max(Date) DESC
RETURN
```

When using this function I get something like:

```
Id      |Name                  | Date
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
32      |Mary       | NULL | 1 |    2015-06-04 00:00:00.000
68      |Joyce      | NULL | 1 |    2015-02-25 00:00:00.000
1069    |James      | NULL | 1 |    2014-03-31 00:00:00.000
1079    |Nwabudike  | NULL | 1 |    2015-06-04 00:00:00.000
1143    |Hala       | NULL | 1 |    2015-03-17 00:00:00.000
```

Which is quite obviously not sorted by date. 
Why is this, and how can I get it to order correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.

The order of the result set is determined *only* by the `order by` in the outermost query.

So, forget the `order by` in the function.  And then call the function as:

```
select t.*
from dbo.tblfunc() t
order by t.date_received desc;
```

EDIT:

To be honest, if `@result` were a "real" table with a clustered, identity, primary key and you inserted the rows using `order by`, then there is quite a good chance that you'd get them back in order.  This is true for smaller tables (because the table is scanned by the clustered index).  I'm not sure if it is always true in a parallel environment.

Comment: Additionally, you could convert the function to inline tvf to improve performance.

Comment: Interesting. If I were to change the `select` to be for  `select top X` is the returned table guaranteed to contain only the `X` most recent entries?

Comment: @Knells . . . Yes, but not necessarily in order.